# How can we create ethereum web wallets?

Tags: wallets

I am looking to create web wallets compatible with ethereum token standards, similar to this: https://wallet.callisto.network/

Can someone guide me to tutorials or guides as how to create this on my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be based on the old version of MyEtherWallet which is open source and you can get that version at https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet.